# Zend framework (1.7.5): how to change controller directory

Tags: php, zend-framework

Using Zend Framework I want to use controllers stored in a directory which is not default.

What I'm trying to achieve is that if the requested path begins with admin/ controllers/admin is used, with layout/admin and views/admin etc.

How would I go about achieving this in a reasonably graceful manner?

Comment: If none of the below answers suits your needs please give a more concrete example because I didn't quite get what you want. Give an example URL and the names for controller, layout and view files. From your current example I could only determine the controller file name. The others not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the module directory structure.  Create the directory structure

```
application
  default
    controllers
    views
    models
  admin
    controllers
    views
    models
```

For more info check out the docs on [Using a Conventional Modular Directory Structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html)

Comment: Hi, it would be great if this answer could somehow be merged with glavić's. I like the modular directory structure and am now using it, but his answer shows how you can let the front controller know that the modules' directory is there. Please edit to include this, I don't have enough rep!

Answer (score 6):

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setControllerDirectory(...path...);
```

OR multiple paths

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setControllerDirectory(array(
    'default' => '/path/to/application/controllers',
    'blog'    => '/path/to/application/blog/controllers'
));
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.front.html

Comment: I upvoted you because you're right but picked the other answer as the chosen one because I like the idea of using the modular directory structure. I did actually try doing what you said and it turns out I was just getting my paths slightly mixed up!

Comment: What I wrote and what Brian Fisher wrote is the same ;)
I don't care what answer you picked, I am just glad that you solved your problem. p.s. tnx for vote up ;)

Comment: Just a Note: If you are calling $front->setControllerDirectory in a bootstrap _init*() method, then it is wise to call `$this->bootstrap('FrontController');` before getting the instance of the front controller. (I spent a few hours dealing with weirdness where the value i passed to setControllerDirectory seemed to get magically overwritten).