# Zend Framework : Subdirectories in controllers directory

Tags: zend-framework, url-routing, controllers, subdirectory

I'm using the Zend Framework for my website, and just created a special module "api" to create... Well, an API.

Now, I have a lot of controllers in my module and I'd like to create subdirectories in this controllers directory in order to "tidy" it. My new structure would be something like this :

```
 - controllers/
 - controllers/contents/[controllers]
 - controllers/users/[controllers]
 - controllers/misc/[controllers]
```

However, I find myself totally unable to find what kind of urls and redirections using Zend_Controller_Router_Route could map to these controllers. Is it possible to do this somehow or should I just go back to the normal structure and put all my controllers in the same directory ?

---

I tried using the separators _ as suggested by smack0007 and as it seemed logical given how Zend Framework usually refers to subdirectories, but I got an error.

---

Edit : Removed the long error text as it was not related to the question since it was only a problem because I didn't use the propre case, believing I had to put an uppercase to the first letter of the directory. All works well now.

Comment: as each controller may have it's own views, i think it's better to use multiple modules. a api_contents module, a api_users module.
i think now go find how to put submodules in a module!

Comment: goto [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592299/zend-framework-1-7-5-how-to-change-controller-directory][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592299/zend-framework-1-7-5-how-to-change-controller-directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this in project back in the 1.5 version but I don't know if it will work anymore.

You have to prefix your controllers with "{FOLDER}_" and then use the full name in the url.

So in your case you would have a controller named:

```
contents_FooController
```

and a route:

```
/contents_foo/index
```

Comment: Well it seems to me that this behaviour has been changed : I try to access to a controller Contents_FooController in a subdirectory "contents" of the "controllers" directory (in the default module), it tells me it can't find it. 

I'll edit the question information with this data.

Comment: Try one thing for me: Rename the "contents" folder to "Contents"

Comment: Let me correct what I was just saying, it does work (edited the wrong directory, sorry), thank you ! I made a mistake by believing I had to put the name of the directory in uppercase, thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish multiple levels at the url for an old application and avoiding to use a lot of url roules.
So I thought about grouping controllers into subdirectories and defining a url roule for it.

For a structure

```
modules
 --test
   --controllers
     --sub
        -- OtherController.php
     --DefaultController.php
```

In the Bootstrap.php of the module I added:

```
public function __construct($application)
    {
        parent::__construct($application);
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $frontController->addControllerDirectory(__DIR__ . '/controllers',
            'test');
        $frontController->addControllerDirectory(__DIR__ . '/controllers/sub',
            'test_sub');
    }
```

DefaultController.php is

```
class Test_DefaultController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
     public function subAction()
    {
         $level1 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('level1');
         $level2 = $this->getRequest()->getParam('level2');
         return $this->_forward($level2, $level1, 'test_sub');
    }
```

So this will forward to our controller in the sub directory.

- "$level1" corresponds to the Controller name, e.g. if $level1 = "other", then we forward to Othercontroller.php
- "$level2" is the action, e.g. $level1 = "add" then addAction() is called.

Finally, added the route:

```
new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)',
    array(),
    array(1 => 'module', 2 => 'controller', 3 => 'action', 4 => 'level1', 5 => 'level2'),
    '%s/%s/%s/%s/%s'
)
```

Now e.g. with a request ***test/default/sub/other/index***, you can call the indexAction in OtherController.php