# Zend Framework folder management for url

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, directory-structure

i have implemented a website with framework CodeIgniter and with folder structure in CodeIgniter like this

```
    /application
        /controller
            /album.php
            /dashboard
                /album.php
            /api
                /album.php
```

and the link like this

```
    //the main page
    site.com/album/

    //dashboard
    site.com/dashboard/album/

    //API
    site.com/api/album/
```

Now I want make website with framework Zend, I am new with this framework, with same link specification like above

What approach should I use? Any help appreciated

Comment: did you read the framework documentation?

Comment: Yes, I have read Zend documentation, but I want the folder structure near CodeIgniter

Comment: from what i see from the zend documentation you can create custom routes, see:https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-router/routing/ for more info

Comment: You can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/37418648/4448410