# Class Not Found when extends a Class of Subdirectory Controller in ZendFramework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, controller

I've the next structure

```
-application
--controllers
---Sub
----DemoController.php
---IndexController.php
-models
-views
-Boostrap.php
```

Well, in my Sub/DemoController.php I've the next:

```
<?php
class Sub_DemoController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'hello demo';
    }
}
```

And my IndexController.php like this:

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Sub_DemoController
{
}
```

When I run my web throw the next error: Class 'Sub_DemoController' not found ...
I try with initialize class with Application_Sub_DemoController, but return the same result.

**I don't want use modules**, I know how uses modules in Zend Framewoork but I don't looking for it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `resourceType` to your resource autoloader add this to you bootstrap file:

```
$this->getResourceLoader()
     ->addResourceType('sub', 'controllers/Sub', 'Sub');
```

More: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html

Comment: I've overwriting the autoloader class but is the solution that I looking for, thnk

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [Zend framework (1.7.5): how to change controller directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592299/zend-framework-1-7-5-how-to-change-controller-directory)

I think you didn't set the controller directory properly or your autoloader does not work.

Comment: I don't want uses module in this case, if I use http://demo.dev/sub_demo it work, I think that Maybe I'll need something type of configuration in my Bootstrapt or similar